# Can anyone help me understand why my target="_blank" does not work?

Tags: html

I have been trying to understand why my target="_blank"  is not working.

My code:

```
 <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1;">
    <a href="subscribe(3).html" target="_blank"><button style="width:50%;padding:12px;margin:8px 0;display:inline-block;border:1px solid #ccc;box-sizing:border-box;background-color:#4caf50;color:white;border:none;">Subscribe</button></a>
  </div>
```

When I put this in SoloLearn Code Playground as a test, it opens up to a new tab, but when I post it on my website, it just sends me to an "Object Not Found" page.

[This image is the "Object Not Found" page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MluDu.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <body style="text-align: center;background-color: #F5F6F7;font-family:Squada One,sans-serif; padding: 20px 0;border:1px solid black;width:450px;margin-left:750px;height:850px;"><h2 style="color:black;">Thank you for subscribing!</h2>
    <img src="https://www.pastepic.xyz/images/2020/02/10/background-image7ce91e998a67b8ab.jpg" alt="background image" style="width:400px;border-radius:20px;"><br /><br /><br /><br /><hr style="width:350px;margin:30px auto;"/><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <a href="HomePage(1)Index.html"
      style="display: block;margin-top: 20px;text-decoration: none;font-weight: bold;">
        <div class="button" style="text-transform: uppercase;background-color: #4caf50;width: 300px;margin: 0 auto;border-radius: 2px;color: #FFF;padding: 26px; font-size:smaller; letter-spacing:.5px;">RETURN TO THE HOME PAGE NOW</div>
      </a>
      <br /><br /><strong>OR</strong><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="index.html"><div class="button" style="background-color: #F05B60;width: 300px;margin: 0 auto;border-radius: 2px;color: #FFF;padding: 26px; font-size:smaller; letter-spacing:.5px;">LOGOUT</div></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I did insert my code, but I do not know what happened to it. Here it is:                 <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1;">
    <a href="subscribe(3).html" target="_blank"><button style="width:50%;padding:12px;margin:8px 0;display:inline-block;border:1px solid #ccc;box-sizing:border-box;background-color:#4caf50;color:white;border:none;">Subscribe</button></a>
  </div>

Comment: add code in question section also

Comment: _“but I do not know what happened to it”_ - please go read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: A 404 Not Found has nothing whatsoever to do with the `target` attribute; it simply means that what you referred to in the `href` attribute did not resolve to an existing URL.

Comment: And FYI, nesting `button` into `a` is illegal in HTML to begin with.

Comment: It looks like the `subscribe(3)` return isn't returning what you want, share that code

Comment: Links cannot contain `button` elements or `input`s. It's invalid HTML.

Comment: i have updated my answer try it..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
 <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1;">
    <a href="subscribe(3).html" target="_blank"><span style="width:50%;padding:12px;margin:8px 0;display:inline-block;border:1px solid #ccc;box-sizing:border-box;background-color:#4caf50;color:white;border:none;text-align:center">Subscribe</span></a>
  </div>
```

use `span` instead of `button`

Comment: You need to check file name and path also.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick! Thank you very much. As you can still, I am very new at coding and am trying to learn. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Kindly accept my answer if this solve your problem :)

Answer (score -1):

`target="_blank"` doesnt seem to be an issue here.. check file path also make sure its in the same folder or specify the complete path to test ...

also you can change the code as i don't see any need to button inside anchor tag.

```css
.btn {
width:50%;padding:12px;margin:8px 0;display:inline-block;border:1px solid #ccc;box-sizing:border-box;background-color:#4caf50;color:white;border:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1;"> 
<a href="subscribe(3).html" target="_blank" class="btn" >Subscribe</a>
</div>
```